# Cannot read property "temp" of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, weather-api

it's my first time here. I'm just starting to learn React and I'm having a little problem creating a weather app. When I try to recall the temp value I get the message: cannot read property "temp" of undefined. I would be very grateful for a hint if someone sees an error. I'm attaching the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export default function Weather() {
  let [city, setCity] = useState("");
  let [weather, setWeather] = useState("");

  function showWeather(response) {
    setWeather(response.data);
  }
  function handleChange(event) {
    setCity(event.target.value);
  }
  function displayTemperature(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=97a9745b0c3a1f932357060a2331ab49&units=metric`;
    axios.get(url).then(showWeather);
  }
  let form = (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={displayTemperature}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {form}
      <ul>
        <li>Temperature: {weather.main.temp}°C</li>
        <li>Description: {weather.weather[0].description}</li>
        <li>Humidity: {weather.main.humidity}%</li>
        <li>Wind: {weather.wind.speed}km/h</li>
        <li>
        <img
            src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weather.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`}
            alt=""></img>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: displayTemperature should be async, 
and you should await the results, 
right now the temp value is undefined as there is noo value and you didn't get a response from your axios call.

Answer (score 2):

In the initial state `weather` is an empty string so before the API hit all the value that you're accessing from `weather` will be not available so you could use either [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
weather?.main?.humidity
```

or && operator

```
weather && Array.isArray(weather) && weather[0].description
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-star-c07gy?file=/src/Weather.js:1135-1194)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export default function Weather() {
  let [city, setCity] = useState("");
  let [weather, setWeather] = useState("");

  function showWeather(response) {
    setWeather(response.data);
  }
  function handleChange(event) {
    setCity(event.target.value);
  }
  function displayTemperature(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=97a9745b0c3a1f932357060a2331ab49&units=metric`;
    console.log(url);
    axios.get(url).then(showWeather);
  }
  function getImageIcon(weather) {
    const value = weather && Array.isArray(weather) && weather[0].icon;
    return value;
  }
  let form = (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={displayTemperature}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {form}
      <ul>
        <li>Temperature: {weather?.main?.temp}°C</li>
        {weather && Array.isArray(weather) && weather[0]?.description}
        <li>
          Description:{" "}
          {weather && Array.isArray(weather) && weather[0].description}
        </li>
        <li>Humidity: {weather?.main?.humidity}%</li>
        <li>Wind: {weather?.wind?.speed}km/h</li>
        <li>
          <img
            src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${getImageIcon()}@2x.png`}
            alt=""
          ></img>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is showing the error because in the beginning the value of `weather` is empty string and you are trying to access the property `main.temp` from it.

You can solve this by using conditional rendering by showing the `list` only when `weather` is not empty.

Also not related to this issue but you should add a catch method in `displayTemperature` method while fetching the data for error handling.

Here is an example below :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Weather() {
  let [city, setCity] = useState("");
  let [weather, setWeather] = useState("");

  function showWeather(response) {
    setWeather(response.data);
  }
  function handleChange(event) {
    setCity(event.target.value);
  }
  function displayTemperature(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=97a9745b0c3a1f932357060a2331ab49&units=metric`;
    axios.get(url)
      .then(showWeather)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  let form = (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={displayTemperature}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {form}
      {/* Conditionally rendering the list */}
      {weather && (
        <ul>
          <li>Temperature: {weather.main.temp}°C</li>
          <li>Description: {weather.weather[0].description}</li>
          <li>Humidity: {weather.main.humidity}%</li>
          <li>Wind: {weather.wind.speed}km/h</li>
          <li>
            <img
              src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weather.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`}
              alt=""></img>
          </li>
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer, especially the idea of ​​using the catch method, now I understand what I did wrong.